# XR Interaction Toolkit - Hover event on UI Elements with XRRayInteractor

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality, toolkit, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to make a VR game on Oculus Quest with the XR Interaction Toolkit and I would like to configure an haptic event when the user is hovering a UI element. The problem is that the haptic event works when I'm hovering a XRGrabInteractable or a TeleportationArea with the XRRayInteractor but not on a canvas. Even the simple hover event (OnHoverUI on the picture) isn't working on the canvas. It's really weird because I can interact with the UI elements (buttons, sliders, ...).

Here are the parameters of my XRRayInteractor :
[XRRayInteractor parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34epU.png)

I already found a solution working without those parameters but it's really annoying. First, I needed to access the controllers (right and left hands). Then, I added a "Event Trigger" component to every single UI element on which I want a haptic feedback. Those triggers have a "Pointer Enter" event calling the "OnHoverUI" function.

```cs
void Start()
{
    var inputDevices = new List<InputDevice>();
    InputDevices.GetDevices(inputDevices);
    foreach (var device in inputDevices)
    {
        if (device.role.ToString() == "LeftHanded")
        {
             leftHand = device;
        }
        else if (device.role.ToString() == "RightHanded")
        {
            rightHand = device;
        }
    }
}

public void OnHoverUI()
{
    if (leftMenuMode) leftHand.SendHapticImpulse(0, 1f, 0.01f);
    else if (rightMenuMode) rightHand.SendHapticImpulse(0, 1f, 0.01f);
}
```

I really would like to use the parameters of the XRRayInteractor but they don't work with the UI.

Does someone have an idea why ?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Could you add some code to show the community the efforts you have already made to solve the issue?

Comment: @rainer I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I found a simple workaround when trying to get "is the XRInteractorRay valid" using `XRInteractorLineVisual.reticle.activeInHierarchy`.

First create two empty GameObjects in the hierarchy, rename them to "leftLineVisual" and "rightLineVisual" respectively and disable both GameObjects. On each of the `XRInteractorLineVisual` scripts (on each XR controller), set the reticle to the corrisponding GameObject in the hierarchy.

You can then get the status of the XR Ray with `XRInteractorLineVisual.reticle.activeInHierarchy` for example

```
[SerializeField] XRInteractorLineVisual leftLineVisual;
[SerializeField] XRInteractorLineVisual rightLineVisual;

void Update() {
    if (rightLineVisual.reticle.activeInHierarchy || leftLineVisual.reticle.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        Debug.Log("One of the pointers is active");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Both of the pointers are disabled");
    }
}
```